# firefox addon main.js is showing same request response, not updating

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

What I'm doing wrong with addon builder? , it is not showing new request response, it show same response all the time, here is my code for main.js :

```
var tmr = require('timer');
var timus=5000;
  var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;

  function timer_restarting(){

  gint = tmr.setInterval(function() {



Request({
  url: "http://mysite.com/data.txt",
  onComplete: function (response) {

     if(response.text.indexOf('<show>true</show>')>-1){ 
         timus = parseInt(response.text.substring(response.text.indexOf('<interval>')+10,response.text.indexOf('</interval>'))); 
         show(response.text.substring(response.text.indexOf('<message>')+9,response.text.indexOf('</message>')));
         tmr.clearInterval(gint);
         timer_restarting();
     }
  }
}).get();


  }, timus);
} 

timer_restarting();
```

the addon show every 5 sec same message, it is not updating . I have an impression like it is not doing new request to server. I have changed message but it still show old message. what is the issue?

please

**UPDATE:**

if I will manually go to that link in browser and refresh it, then addon will refresh the respone as well. Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a [header](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/modules/sdk/request.html#Request%28options%29) for '[Cache-control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9)' to your `Request` instance, and specify a value of '`no-cache`' (or some '`max-age`' value), to prevent getting a cached response.

E.g. in your example, between the lines

```js
  url: "http://mysite.com/data.txt",
  onComplete: function (response) { /* ... */ }
```

insert the following lines:

```js
  url: "http://mysite.com/data.txt",
  headers: {
    'Cache-control': 'no-cache'
  },
  onComplete: function (response) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I'm new to addon builder sdk, please show me a code if you have. thanks